# Oblivious Universal Turing Machine in O(T log(T)) time

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, simulation

I'm currently reading [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf). In this book, they give a proof of a universal Turing machine $U$ such that if $M(x)$ runs in $T$ steps, then $U(\lfloor M \rfloor, x)$ runs in $CT \log T$ steps where $C$ depends **only** on $M$'s alphabet size, number of tapes, and number of states. I'll describe $U$ loosely here:

> It has an input tape, output tape, tape for $M$'s states and transition functions, tape for $M$'s current state, and one work tape. We say $M$ has $k$ work tapes and an alphabet of $\Gamma$.
>
> $U$ uses an alphabet of $\Gamma^k$ to put the letters of all $k$ tapes on one cell and has a clever way of imitating the left and right shifts of different heads.
>
> Since we only have $T$ steps, we only need to go from $-T$ to $T$. We'll say $L_i$ goes from $2^i$ to $2^{i+1}-1$ and $R_i$ goes from $-2^{i+1}+1$ to $-2^i$. This goes from $i=0$ to $i=\log T+1$. For any $i$, $L_i$ and $R_i$ is full of blank symbols, half-blank half-filled, or completely filled. Furthermore, the total number of blank symbols in both $L_i$ and $R_i$ at one time is $2^i$, meaning half of all of the cells are blank while the other half is information.
>
> To left shift, find the smallest $i$ so $R_i$ is not empty and thus $L_i$ is not full. Put the leftmost non-blank symbol in position $0$ (i.e. under the head in $M$) and move the other $2^{i-1}-1$ non-blank symbols into the empty $R_0,R_1,...R_{i-1}$. This leaves all of those zones half-empty.
>
> Push the $2^{i-1}$ leftmost non-blank symbols in $L_{i-1},...,L_1$ into $L_i$ and then reorganize the other non-blank symbols to make $L_{i-1},...,L_1$ all half-full.
>
> Right shifts look similarly, except switch the roles of the left and right zones.

I want to solve the following exercise:

> Define a TM $M$ to be oblivious if its head movement does not depend on the input but only on the input length. That is, M is oblivious if for every input $x \in \{0, 1\}^∗$ and $i \in N$, the location of each of $M$’s heads at step $i$ of execution on input $x$ is only a function of $\lvert x \rvert$ and $i$. Show that for any time-constructible $T : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$, if $L \in \mathbf{DTIME}(T(n))$, then there is an oblivious TM that decides $L$ in $O(T(n)\log T(n))$ time.
>
> **Hint:** Show that $U$ can be tweaked to be oblivious.

Now, my question is, under such a machine, while maintaining $CT\log T$ time, how do we make $U$ oblivious? I see how putting the input down initially and the left/right shifts are simply functions of $\lvert x \rvert$, but when we decide to left/right shift each tape has to decide on $x$ since we're not given that $T$ is oblivious, so **how do we time the left and right shifts of $U$ so that they only depend on $\lvert x \rvert$ and not on the actual content of $x$**?

Comment: Check this blog post for a hint: https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/oblivious-turing-machines-and-a-crock/.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Your link has a bunch of weird characters at the end of it, so it doesn't work. However, I found [the correct link](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/oblivious-turing-machines-and-a-crock/). Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you please help me with this question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87186/a-question-about-ot-log-t-simulation-of-a-tm-on-some-input-by-universal-tur?

Answer (score 2):

A concrete construction of such a UTM, from which one can construct oblivious and efficient TMs, is given in this lecture note https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse531/16wi/lectures/lect01.pdf.

A crucial idea in the construction is rearranging $L_{i+2}$ and $R_{i+2}$ EVERY $2^i$ steps. The invariant ($L_i$ and $R_i$ are empty, half-full or full) does not hold every steps in this construction. However, we can see that it holds when the rearrangement occurs.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  It is common for the links to lecture notes for university become broken.  Please read [What is StackExchange's take on link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/91358)